# navigation button not working properly

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm having a big problem with my navigation buttons. I'm using a [plugin for image scroll](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/rotators/images-rotators/8742). In which I wanted to add navigation buttons and I'm facing the following problems:

Without user clicks to buttons it goes to next button activated, and even if the user click to forward buttons then also it goes to next button activated. But when user click again backward button it's not having activated and but image is scrolling.

And from the last button it should go to first button which is having problem.

Also I wanted to remove firstly the repeated image so no problem will appear but having some problem.

whole code in navigation.js is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPzUn/)

----- tried to remove repeated images like this ------

```
// remove duplicates from first
        var classes = [];
$("#banner img").each(function(id, vl) {
    $this = $(this), cls = $this.attr("class");

    if( $.inArray(cls, classes) < 0 ) {
        classes.push(cls);
    }
});
for(var c = 0; c < classes.length; c++ ) {
    if( $("#banner img."+classes[c]).length > 1 ) {
        $("#banner img."+classes[c]+":first").remove();
    }
}
// end remove

//remove duplicate images from last
    var seen = {};
$('#banner img').each(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    if (seen[className])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[className] = true;
});
    //end remove
```

Where did I use these codes I've commented in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPzUn/1/)
But I've not implemented this in my live site as my other previous problem occurred.

<s>[current live site](http://nepotech.com/kldugar)</s>

---

My key problem is that if you wait while one image block comes to left then it goes to next navigation button automatically and also if you click to another button and wait for a while its corresponding image goes to left, no problem until now But the problem occurs when you click again to previous button then it is not activated.

> This question may be irritating but please don't feel so coz **I will award +1000 bounty** for this question whoever solves the problem

Comment: Sorry I have deleted my comment. I work on that. But your plugin takes many graphics ressources, it makes boil my mac which has a high configuration.

Comment: not.... so I've removed current live site..... cos automatically navigating removed......

Comment: Is the live link the one in the post? which are the navigation buttons?

Comment: yeah the live site is still there but I've disabled the automatic button but you can see the previously applied code in the fiddle provided in the question.

Comment: in the scrolling top banner there you'll see the buttons...

Comment: you mean the buttons in the slide/scroll

Comment: yes..... there are 10 buttons currently on site

Comment: I could rollback previous if you want to check........for automatic....

Comment: Ok, I have rollbacked ,,, just wait to see automatically goes to next li after one picture block is gone to left but after you click the automatic function don't work... when you click to previous button

Comment: Do you want the images to go back to left when they reach the end or to continue and just the buttons starts from left again?

Comment: I can manage that but my key problem is with buttons...and the image is to continue .....

Comment: When a button is clicked should it go forwards always or back in case the img is on the left side?

Comment: if previous button clicked then it goes to back.... you could see in my current site there is not working only for previous button click but works only clicked again....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="banner" class="cf">
    <ul id="navs">
        <li class="navs1 activenav"></li>
        <li class="navs2"></li>
        <li class="navs3"></li>
        <li class="navs4"></li>
        <li class="navs5"></li>
        <li class="navs6"></li>
        <li class="navs7"></li>
        <li class="navs8"></li>
        <li class="navs9"></li>
        <li class="navs10"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="moduletable">
        <div class="ic_marquee1" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="visibility: visible; width: 100%; height: 400px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; white-space: nowrap; top: 0px;">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-01.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img1">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-02.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img2">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-03.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img3">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-04.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img4">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-05.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img5">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-06.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img6">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-07.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img7">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-08.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img8">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-09.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img9">
                    <img src="/kldugar/images/topbanner/img-10.jpg" alt="" style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline; vertical-align: top;" class="img10">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var anim;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var img_block = $('#banner img');
    $('#navs li').on('click', function () {
        clearInterval(anim_interval);
        $('#navs li').removeClass('activenav');
        $(this).addClass('activenav');
        var lisindx = $(this).index();
        var b = $('#banner img').parent('div');
        var imgwidth = 0;
        for (var j = lisindx + 1; j > 1; j--) {
            imgwidth += $('#banner .img' + j).width();
        }
        var imgspace = lisindx * 7;
        imgwidth = -(imgwidth + imgspace);

        b.animate({
            left: imgwidth
        }, 1000, function () {
            anim_interval = setInterval(anim, 30);
        });
        thisidx = lisindx; //alert(thisidx);
        thisimg = $('#banner .img' + (thisidx + 1) + ':first');
        crawl_left = -imgwidth;
    }); //end click 
    var thisli = $('#navs .activenav');
    var thisidx = thisli.index();
    var thisimg = $('#banner img:first');
    console.log(thisimg.offset().left);
    var crawl_left = 0;
    var b = $('#banner img').parent('div');

    anim = function () {
        crawl_left++;
        var w = thisimg.offset().left + thisimg.width() / 2; //alert(w);
        var nextoff = w > 0; //alert(nextoff);
        var navlis = $('#navs li');
        var b = $('#banner img').parent('div');
        b.css('left', -crawl_left + 'px')
        if (crawl_left > ($('#banner img').length - 2) * thisimg.width()) {
            var b = $('#banner img').parent('div');
            b.append(img_block.clone());
        }
        if (nextoff) {
            return false;
        }
        var nextli = navlis.filter('.activenav').removeClass('activenav').next();
        if (!nextli.length) {
            nextli = navlis.first();
            nextli.addClass('activenav');
        }
        nextli.addClass('activenav');
        thisli = $('#navs .activenav');
        thisidx = thisli.index() + 1;
        thisimg = $('#banner .img' + thisidx).last();
    }; //end anim
    var anim_interval = setInterval(anim, 30);
}); //end document ready
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dye84/2/)

Comment: That's fine. But the same code I placed in my site but its not working properly check. you can check live site.....

Comment: @C-Link I don't see my code on your page. Remove your `navigation.js` and put my code on the main page to test.

Comment: firebug> scripts > see navigation.js there

Comment: I've done perfectly with window.setInterval but when user clicks then automatic function not work... http://jsfiddle.net/Dye84/1/ .... but here in the fiddle it's even not working without user click (automatic) can you check this please.....

Comment: @C-Link Yes,I will check. I will go to my job now but I will check it later again. Could you try with my html on your page also meanwhile. Cheers

Comment: @C-Link, ok. This will be working soon :) I changed my jQuery code, please update. Like this I can change `var anim;` and test it on the console.

Comment: I knew seeing your code that I was just doing wrong in this line: b.animate({left: totimgwidth}, 1000); here I've to define the function b.animate({left: totimgwidth}, 1000, function(){......}); but I've declared in $(window).load() can you suggest me here how can I set function which is window.load() just I've provided you in this http://jsfiddle.net/Dye84/1/ this will be working for my site as I'm using the plugin...

Comment: I've decided to use the modified answer by removing the plugin. But there is one problem after last last button active then it goes to first but then doesn't work. I've tried a lot but could not success. Can you try please?

Comment: @C-Link, sure. I can check. Which version should I check? fiddle or live link?

Comment: @C-Link, did not have much time to see this until today... check this http://jsfiddle.net/6mNDr/

Comment: yeah alright seems okay thanks.  on mouseenter (in the image and buttons) the scrolling should be paused and on mouseleave play again

Comment: @C-Link, great! Check this last fiddle for the pause function -http://jsfiddle.net/LuZBe/ - if you want it to restart moving after the scroll,remove the comment (//) on line 20. Glad I could help!

Comment: I din't understand moving  after the scroll?? anyway I'm having a little problem if I click to last button it's having gap coz of cloning after animation you can see live site what's happening. just click to last button.

Comment: and another great change I was doing previously when clicked thereafter the previous images should be appended to the last but not to whole images, you can take your free time for this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mootools and Jquery conflicts or multiple libraries...try this http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327 or another plugin for joomla....or add noconflict in your theme http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327

Comment: there's no mootools used in my site.

Comment: Yes u have <script src="/kldugar/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> on line 114....

Comment: Mootools does not use the `$` if its already taken, so I don't think the problem is Mootools.

Answer (score -1):

With this changes, it works for me

**navigation.js**

```
$('#navs li').on('click', function(){
    $('#navs li').removeClass('activenav');

    $(this).addClass('activenav');

    var lisindx = $(this).index();
    lisindx += 1;
    var b = $('#banner img').parent('div');
    b.find('img:lt(' + lisindx + ')').clone().remove().appendTo(b);


    var imgwidth = 0;
    for(var j=lisindx; j>1; j--){
        imgwidth += $('#banner .img' + j).width();
    }
    var imgspace = (lisindx - 1) * 7;
    imgwidth = -(imgwidth + imgspace);

    b.animate({left: imgwidth}, 1000);

    thisimg = $('#banner .img' + thisidx);          
}); //end click
```

Comment: when you click to next li button it is activated automatically to next button.

Comment: So if you think that it don't work. Maybe I haven't understood your problem. I have download your website in local to try and I have no problem on Safari, Chrome and Firefox. I don't see a irregular behavior. And I think nobody will see problems because it's not the most important part in your website.

Comment: if it was not important, I would have managed something like you and wouldn't asked here.

Comment: I agree with you but the most important problem is resolved. When I am arrived in your website, I saw the problem in your navigation bar but now I see any problem.So if you think my answer was not helpful, I can't help you anymore without to see the problem. Good luck.